# Подскажите аналоги adobe air

Tags: веб-программирование, html, air

Подскажите аналоги adobe air или других приложений , которые помогут преобразовать веб приложение в обычный exe файл. Желательно без привлечения других языков программирования.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. [WebExe](http://www.webexe.com/)
2. [WebSiteZip Packer](http://www.spadixbd.com/wsz/)
3. [WebSite Compiler](http://www.byterun.com/website-compiler.php)